# Removing a Specific Char From a List

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-manipulation

What I want to know is if there is a built-in-function with the Python Library that would remove a specific character from a list?

EG:

In this case I want to remove all of the zeroes from the list, how would I do that.

```
[76499618373903541704700923371133789862262100000000000000000000000]
```

Note: This list has only  1 value

Comment: Is this the list of values? [x, y ..... z] ?

Comment: This is all one list with one value

Comment: I have posted the answer. The doubt I am having is why you are storing just one value in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to divide by 10, as long as the number is divisible by 10:

```
def remove_zeros(number):
    while number and number % 10 == 0:
        number //= 10
    return number

number_in_a_list = [764996183739035417047009233711337898622621000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000]

result = [remove_zeros(n) for n in number_in_a_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way will be to convert it to the string and strip the zeroes from the last:

```
nums =[7649900000000000000]
result = [int(str(n).rstrip('0')) for n in nums]
print result  # You will get: [76499]
```

Comment: Will this work if my list is something like this: nums =[769845485004540]?

Comment: Yes, and the result will 76984548500454. Instead of asking, you will get better idea if you'll try it by yourself. Python is a great language. Spend some time playing with it. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> f = lambda n: n % 10 ==0 and f(n//10) or n
>>> f(764996183739035417047009233711337898622621000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
764996183739035417047009233711337898622621
```